# Configure Swashbuckle (OpenAPI) to Ignore Namespace in Models

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, openapi, swashbuckle

On the generated swagger page in the `Model` section, how does one get Swashbuckle to not report the whole namespace, but just the model?

`MyNamespace.SubFolder.MyModel`

to

`MyModel`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to define custom schema id's either through an `ISchemaFilter`
or create your own "schema id strategy" read: [Customizing Schema Id's](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#customize-schema-ids)

> ```
> services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
> {
>     ...
>     c.CustomSchemaIds((type) => type.FullName);
> };
> ```

You could create a base model class that contains a name property  (remember to `[JsonIgnore]`) use that property for the strategy.